# generate conditional block with automake

Tags: gnu-make, automake

What sort of black magic I need to add to Makefile.am so that resulting Makefile could contain regular conditional make statements:

```
ifeq ($(SOMETHING),1)
target:
    do this
else
target:
    do that
endif
```

Please, note, that I ask exactly what I ask, no workarounds, or automake conditionals, I need that conditional in final makefile.

Comment: Try `AC_SUBST_FILE` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start out with the obvious small change:

```
target:
ifeq ($(SOMETHING),1)
    do this
else
    do that
endif
```

If this doesn't do it, please elaborate more on why it is that you need a conditional in the final Makefile. Otherwise this feels like an XY problem.